# Notify Parent ViewModel in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I am writing a **Windows 8.1 Store App** in **C#**, **MVVM** Pattern.

I have 3 ViewModels:
 1. BaseViewModel
 2. StudentViewModel
 3. StudentDashboardViewModel

Its like:

- I added **BaseViewModel**.
- I inherited **StudentViewModel** from BaseViewModel.
- Then, I inherited **StudentDashboardViewModel** from  StudentViewModel.

I made a Page **StudentDashboardPage** and I binded it to **StudentDashboardViewModel**.

I am trying to change a property example, **IsBlackIn** in **StudentViewModel** via another class but the problem is that it is not notifying its child viewmodel **StudentDashboardViewModel**.

So, how to notify child viewmodel of changes in parent viewmodel.
Here is the code:

**BaseViewModel:**

```
 public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
        {
            if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            {
                return false;
            }
            storage = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
            return true;
        }
        protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            var eventHandler = this.PropertyChanged;
            if (eventHandler != null)
            {
                eventHandler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }            
    }
```

**StudentViewModel:**

```
 public class StudentViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {    
        private static StudentViewModel studentViewModel;            
        public static StudentViewModel Singleton()
        {
            if (studentViewModel == null)
            {
                studentViewModel = new StudentViewModel();
            }
            return studentViewModel;
        } 

        private bool _IsBlackIn = false;
        public bool IsBlackIn
        {
            get { return _IsBlackIn; }
            set
            {
                SetProperty<bool>(ref _IsBlackIn, value);               
            }
        }   
    }
```

**StudentDashboardViewModel:**

```
public class StudentDashboardViewModel : StudentViewModel
{
    public static StudentDashboardViewModel studentDashboardViewModel;

    public static StudentDashboardViewModel GetSingleInstance()
    {
        return studentDashboardViewModel ?? (studentDashboardViewModel = new StudentDashboardViewModel());
    }

}
```

**StudentDashboardPage page behind code:**

```
public sealed partial class StudentDashboardPage : Page
{
    private StudentDashboardViewModel studentDashvm;

    public StudentDashboardPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();         
        this.Loaded += StudentDashboardPage_Loaded;
    }

    private void StudentDashboardPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.studentDashvm = StudentDashboardViewModel.GetSingleInstance();
        this.DataContext = studentDashvm;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Back to MVVM fundamentals. Why are your ViewModels singleton in first place? ViewModel is supposed to be alive only as long as the corresponding View is displayed and not throughout the application lifespan.

Comment: I am planning to revert back from singleton but, what about Notify problem?

Comment: View-models can outlive their views and even be shared by multiple views, but I agree that they shouldn't be singletons.

Comment: If you change property's value in base class once the derived class is binded to the UI, its value will not reflect in the UI. so you do it in the dervied class i.e. in StudentDashboardViewModel class. And i agree this is not a good practice to use ViewModels as singleton.

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 ways i can see the `StudentDashboardViewModel` can get notified of any change that can occur to the `IsBlackIn` property defined in `StudentViewModel`:

1. Make `SetProperty<T>` (in BaseViewModel) virtual and override in `StudentDashboardViewModel` and check the name of the property.
2. Make the setter of the `IsBlackIn` property in `StudentViewModel` virtual and override in `StudentDashboardViewModel`.

In the previous two cases don't forget to call the base method whether that was `SetProperty<T>` or `IsBlackIn` setter.

The third option you have is to compose the view models (use composition over inheritance). That is, let `StudentDashboardViewModel` receive an instance of `StudentViewModel` and then listen to an event that notifies the change of IsBlackIn. You can either listen to `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` or implement your own custom event.

Comment: Option 3, Option 3! For the love of all things holy!